# How to remove slashes while adding scripts on umbraco cms

Tags: javascript, debugging, plugins, umbraco7

I'm facing an issue on umbraco cms, while i'm adding scripts to the pages its adding a slash for each insertion of scripts on the frontend pages.
Please suggest how to remove those slashes.

[image]

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Macros.PartialViewMacroPage
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       if ($("html").attr("lang") == "ar-AE") {
          $(".globe").attr('href', '/about-us/');
       } else {
           $(".globe").attr('href', '/من-نحن/');
       }
   });
 </script>
```

Comment: Where/how are you adding scripts?

Comment: by macro with partial classes

Comment: Can you include your code please that's embedding the scripts?

Comment: @Tim I have provided the script, suggest your comments.

Comment: I suspect it’s not the script that’s adding the slashes - can you post your code for rendering the macro?  How are you inserting it?